# Python pygame balls moving

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, draw, geometry

I am writing a simple "game" and I have three questions for you:

1. How can I make all the balls moving independetly?
2. When I drag a ball with a mouse and click on the screen, how can i make the ball stay there. I want to draw it on that specific coordinate where the mouse key was pressed. It has to stay there all the time.
3. If a small ball touches the large one it shoud become a large one and dissapear after 10 seconds.

I have no idea how to do this. Can you please help me.

My code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600

fps = 25
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

display_window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Bouncy')
game_over = False

r = random.randint(0, 255)
g = random.randint(0, 255)
b = random.randint(0, 255)

x_cor = random.randint(15, width - 15)
y_cor = random.randint(15, height - 15)

x_change = random.randint(3, 7)
y_change = random.randint(3, 7)

coordinates = []

for i in range(10):
    x = random.randint(0, width)
    y = random.randint(0, height)
    coordinates.append([x, y])

while not game_over:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    if event.type == pygame.mouse.get_pressed():
        pass

x_cor += x_change
y_cor += y_change

display_window.fill(white)

mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

for coordinate in coordinates:
    pygame.draw.circle(display_window, (r, g, b), (coordinate[0],    coordinate[1]), 15, 0)

pygame.draw.circle(display_window, black, (mouse_x, mouse_y), 25, 0)

pygame.draw.circle(display_window, (r, g, b), (x_cor, y_cor), 15, 0)

if x_cor > (width - 15) or x_cor < 15:
    x_change = x_change * -1
if y_cor > (height - 15)or y_cor < 15:
    y_change = y_change * -1

clock.tick(fps)
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your coding and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: create class Ball to keep ball position, speed and check mouse click, etc. Your questions are too broad - answers need a lot of code.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, do the research required before you post here (see the help documents on the intro tour).  There are many tutorials on the Internet, and many answered questions in SO (StackOverflow) that deal with moving objects.  To get you started in general:

1. You move the balls independently by keeping a separate set of coordinates for each ball.  On each iteration of the game clock, you have to reiterate the new coordinates of each ball.
2. To make a ball stay in one place, simply do not change its coordinates.
3. To change the size of a ball, draw it with a larger radius.  This means that you also have to remember the radius of each ball.  To give it a 10-second lifetime, keep a "lifespan" for each ball; decrement it on each tick of the game clock.

Bascially, you need a **Ball** object (make a class Ball); instantiate a new object for each ball you need.  Write methods to change the position, size, and life span of each ball.